# How to connect to Mongo using NestJS and "forRootAsync"?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs

I'm unable to connect to Mongo async using `MongooseModule.forRootAsync`.

Here's the config that I'm using:

```
ConfigModule.forRoot({
    isGlobal: true,
    envFilePath: ['.env'],
    cache: false,
}),

// ...

MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    useClass: MongodbConfigService,
})
```

The config class:

```
@Injectable()
export class MongodbConfigService implements MongooseOptionsFactory {
    constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {}

    createMongooseOptions():
        | MongooseModuleOptions
        | Promise<MongooseModuleOptions> {
        console.log(this.configService.get<string>('MONGODB_HOST')); // mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb
        return {
            uri: this.configService.get<string>('MONGODB_HOST'),
            useNewUrlParser: true,
        };
    }
}
```

When I start the app using `npm run start:dev` I get this error:

> querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.lys1va8.mongodb.net
> Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.lys1va8.mongodb.net
> at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:173:17)

my `.env` file contains a local (docker) mongo URI, I've printed using `console.log` and the connection string is correct;

```
MONGODB_HOST=mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb
```

Where this `_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.lys1va8.mongodb.net` is coming from? Could be cached from nestjs? (it looks like an atlas URI that I was using)

Comment: If you run `echo $MONGODB_HOST` what do you get? I don't think the `.env` will override a value that is already there. But I may be mistaken

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki nothing